# Angular 2 101: defining and using a variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template

All I'm trying to do is get my head around Angular 2 syntax. The examples I find seem to use different methods.

Look at **foo**:

Is this how I set up every single variable I want to use?

I define it using : syntax, and specify its type?
Then later I refer to it with this.?

```
export class SwitchClientComponent implements OnInit {
    filterString: string = '';
    foo: string ='';


    ngOnInit() {

        this.foo = localStorage.getItem('bar') || '!';
    }
```

.

```
    <span>[{{foo}}]</span>
```

Comment: In anguarjs we access varibles by {{Varible name}}  <span>{{foo}}</span>

Comment: You should begin by learning correct terminology. You are referring to **properties**, not variables.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the Angular 2 Docs, there's a section about [Template Variables](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

**Interpolation**

The way you show a variable in the template using `{{}}` is called interpolation.

```html
<h3>
  The title is: {{title}}
  <img src="{{heroImageUrl}}" style="height:30px">
</h3>
```

As you see you can use interpolated variables even in attributes, even mixed to static Text

**Attribute Binding**

Some attributes can be surrounded by square brackets which tells Angular to bind the value passed to that variable. In this case you don't need to use the `{{}}` syntax.

```html
<img [src]="heroImageUrl">
```

**Template Expressions**

Also you can perform expressions and use the returning value of functions

```html
<p>The sum of 1 + 1 is not {{1 + 1 + getVal()}}</p>
```

Of course `getVal()` will be a function that needs to be defined as public in the component.

**Local Template Variables**

Also keep in mind you can define template variables on the fly, for example using an `ngFor` directive

```html
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{hero.name}}</div>
```

In this example `hero` is not defined in the Component (and will NOT be visible inside the component class by calling `this.hero`) but it will be local to the context of the `ngFor` block. Meaning: all the children elements of the `div` containing `ngFor`.

The array `heores` instead need to exist and be public in the Component. As you can see in this case you don't need to use the `{{}}` syntax. This is because Angular is already expecting a variable there and automatically interpolates anything you will put in there.

```html
<input #heroInput> {{heroInput.value}}
```

This syntax instead provides a reference to the `input` DOM element.
`heroInput` will then be visible inside the template but cannot be accessed directly from inside the component (there is a way to use it from the component though).

There are some more rules around but reading that article should give you all the info you need.

**Define Component public variables**

The component to use all the examples above would look like this:

```js
export class MyComponent {
    title: string = 'My title';
    heroImageUrl: string ='http://www.myurl.com/img.jpg';
    heroes: any[] = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}];

    getVal() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be just **`{{foo}}`** without the square brackets **`[]`**

```
<span>{{foo}}</span>
```

Comment: Yeah. I use square brackets as placeholders, in case the variable contains an empty string. :) I'm more concerned about foo: string ='';

Comment: so what is the issue ?

Comment: Coming from Angular 1, I have not seen this before:  foo: string ='';

Comment: it is typescript, you are initialising a string variable foo with empty value

Comment: And for an array it's arr: any[] = []; ?

Comment: @DaveC426913 yes. you can also just do without mentioning type  foo ='';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148342/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-davec426913).

Comment: did the answer help ?